# Get S3 bucket increase per day using get-metric-statistics

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to use the cloudwatch cli command `get-metric-statistics` to retrieve bucket size increase per day but it's returning an empty array. Am I missing something obvious?

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
  --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --namespace AWS/S3 \
  --start-time 2021-10-01T00:00:00Z --end-time 2021-10-31T00:00:00Z \
  --statistics Maximum --unit Bytes --region eu-west-1 \
  --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=my-bucket Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage \
  --period 86400 --query 'Datapoints[*].[Timestamp, Maximum]'
```

Comment: I used your command to get the data from my account, so the command is good (you can remove the query part, not used in get-metric-statistics). Check the bucket name, region and the creds used.

Comment: Yes now it works. Must've misspelled the bucket name or used the wrong profile